# getting my calculator to work

Tags: javascript, calculator

Ok, so I have this code here and what I am trying to do is read in a character for supersize and if the value is "y" then multiply the price times 1.5 to show fifty percent increase. I'm not really sure where my error is here....

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org     /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>

var products=[0,2,3,5,7,8,9,12];
var prices=[3.59,4.99,2.59,1.99,2.99,4.29,3.19,5.29];
var taxes=.06;

var forimages=new Array();

for (var j=0;j<products.length;j++) {
    forimages[j]=new Image(200,200);
    forimages[j].src="chesssmall.jpg";
    }


var thequantity=0;
var thebill=0;
var thetax=0;
var thetotal=0;

var thecode;
var hits=0;

var qbox;

function computebill(form) {

    qbox=document.getElementById("quantity");
    hits=0; 
    thecode=parseFloat(form.code.value);    
    thequantity=parseFloat(form.numbuy.value);


for (var i=0;i<=products.length;i++) {

    //why is there an increment thing on the indidual variable below

    if (thecode==products[i]){
    document.main.src=forimages[i].src;

    if(ssize=="y"){

    form.price.value=prices[i]; 


    thebill+=(prices[i]*1.5)*thequantity;
    form.bill.value=thebill.toFixed(2);


    thetax+=(prices[i]*1.5)*thequantity*taxes[i];
    form.tax.value=thetax.toFixed(2);

    thetotal=thebill+thetax;
    form.total.value=thetotal.toFixed(2);
    }
    else{


    form.price.value=prices[i]; 


    thebill+=(prices[i])*thequantity;
    form.bill.value=thebill.toFixed(2);


    thetax+=(prices[i])*thequantity*taxes[i];
    form.tax.value=thetax.toFixed(2);

    thetotal=thebill+thetax;
    form.total.value=thetotal.toFixed(2);
    }

    hits=1; 
    break;
    }
}

if (hits==0) {
    form.code.value="Item Not Found";

        }

    form.code.focus();
    form.code.select();
}

</script>

<style type="text/css">
.ql {
    background-color: #fff;
}
</style>


</head>

<body>
<div style="float:left">
 <form>
  <table width="377" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="158">Enter Product Code</td>
      <td width="232"><input type="text" name="code" id="code" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quantity Buying</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="numbuy" id="numbuy" /></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td>Supersize?</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="ssize" id="ssize" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The Price</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bill</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="bill" id="bill" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tax      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tax" id="tax" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Bill</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="total" id="total" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="button" name="forsum" id="forsum" value="Add" onclick="computebill(this.form)"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</form>
</div>
<img src="window2.jpg" width="200" height="200" name="main" id="main"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing ssize declared anywhere?

Comment: `ssize` is an input element; it can never equal `"y"` which is a string.

Comment: You should declare ssize in your javascript like this: `var ssize = document.getElementById("ssize").value;`

Answer (score -1):

On a stylistic point, rather than:

```
                if(ssize=="y"){

                        form.price.value=prices[i];


                        thebill+=(prices[i]*1.5)*thequantity;
                        form.bill.value=thebill.toFixed(2);


                        thetax+=(prices[i]*1.5)*thequantity*taxes[i];
                        form.tax.value=thetax.toFixed(2);

                        thetotal=thebill+thetax;
                        form.total.value=thetotal.toFixed(2);
                }
                else{


                        form.price.value=prices[i];


                        thebill+=(prices[i])*thequantity;
                        form.bill.value=thebill.toFixed(2);


                        thetax+=(prices[i])*thequantity*taxes[i];
                        form.tax.value=thetax.toFixed(2);

                        thetotal=thebill+thetax;
                        form.total.value=thetotal.toFixed(2);
                }
```

do this:

```
                var theprice = prices[i];
                if(ssize=="y"){
                        theprice *= 1.5;
                }


                form.price.value=theprice;

                thebill+=theprice*thequantity;
                form.bill.value=thebill.toFixed(2);


                thetax+=theprice*thequantity*taxes[i];
                form.tax.value=thetax.toFixed(2);

                thetotal=thebill+thetax;
                form.total.value=thetotal.toFixed(2);
```

There are two reasons to suggest this. First, your code says what it means -- namely, in one exceptional case, add 50% to the price, but do everything else the same. Second, it's much easier to add a logging or output statement here to debug what's really wrong with your environment.

Cheers.

Comment: but every time i run the code, wont it continue to multiply the price times 1.5? since it loops

Comment: Try it. See what happens. This sounds like a question about pass by value versus pass by reference semantics. Take a look at some other answers to get some clarity on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value